# Can't read serial response using pyserial

Tags: pyserial

Trying to use pyserial to talk to a Korad KD3005P power supply. (Using Python 3.6)

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1)
ser.write(b'VSET1:2')
ser.write(b'VOUT1?')
response = ser.readline()
print(response)
```

`VSET1:2` sets the voltage to 2 volts

`VOUT1?` tells the device to return the current voltage.

But all I get from the `VOUT1?` part seems to be:

> b''

Stuff I've checked or tried without success:

- The device works - I can talk to the device and get responses successfully with these commands through a serial terminal like CuteCom
- Pyserial is *kinda* working - if I run the above program, the `VSET1:2` does change the voltage.
- I've tried different timeouts
- I've tried `ser.read()` instead with various bit lengths
- I've tried putting the read commands in a while loop

Any suggestions?

Comment: You most likely need to end those commands with a `\r` and/or `\n` to get the device to act on them.

Comment: Yeah I'd already tried that too. Sorry, forgot to add it to my list.

Answer (score 0):

Oh.

It's a timing thing of some kind. Removing the `VSET` command or putting a `time.sleep()` command in between them and voila.. I get a response.

I'm going to mark this resolved but if anyone can enlighten me as to the nuances of this, thanks.